# Hide downloaded HTML page's folder

Tags: command-line, 16.10, cinnamon, offline, websites

I'm switching from Windows to Ubuntu and I'm quite a beginner in GNU/Linux in general.

I download many web pages to consult them offline and I want to hide folders related to them.(the folder containing the images, the CSS, the Javascript...) 
I know I have to put a period before the folder's name.

But when I want to hide this folder then the elements (images, CSS...) aren't shown because the HTML page point to `webpage_files/something.css` and no `.webpage_files/something.css`

I run on Ubuntu 16.10 and my desktop environment is Cinnamon.
Some informations about my Packard Bell laptop:

```
$ uname -a
Linux zubuntu 4.8.0-59-generic #64-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 29 19:38:34 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Thanks.

EDIT:
I want files to be hidden in the terminal. I already tried the .hidden file trick and it didn't work.

EDIT 2:
Many users marked my question as duplicate. Are you stupid ?
Excuse my language but I posted this question one week ago and all you find to do is mark my question as duplicate ?
If you read carefully my question you will see that I want my files hidden in the **TERMINAL**, not in nautilus.

Comment: Actually 16.10 reached the end of its lifecycle 3 days ago and is no longer supported. You should upgrade to 17.04 as soon as possible.